# Magento2: Cart product delete after 10 minutes

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

How to increase the guest cart session? Let me know how is it possible.

Comment: What is the value in Your Store->Configurations->Web->Session Cookie Management->Cookie Lifetime ?

Comment: Now, the Default set as 3600. @KishorThummar

Comment: Check my answer, Hope it will work for you.

Comment: default 3600 means how much in a min? @KishorThummar

Comment: Its 60 minutes.

Comment: But the session was expiring after 10 min. How? @KishorThummar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104558/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-kishor-thummar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please apply below configurations
In your php.ini file:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

In your Magento admin:

```
Store->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management
```

and set the **Cookie Lifetime** to **86400**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I will check and update you. Thanks!

Comment: It's working. Thanks